# Issue in corners of room

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a home builder system in unity 3d. To create a room I create cubes using the corner points of the room. The issue is, the cubes do not just fit perfectly at the corners. I can adjust my code for a rectangular or square room, but issue will remain in case of triangluar room etc. I'm attaching some images to show you guys the issue.
[[You can see corner points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxFT2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHg2g.png)

The code is given below

```
 
    public LineRenderer line;
    public GameObject myCube;
    Vector3 posC = Vector3.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            DrawAWallStructure(line.GetPosition(0) , line.GetPosition(1));
            DrawAWallStructure(line.GetPosition(1) , line.GetPosition(2));
            DrawAWallStructure(line.GetPosition(2),line.GetPosition(3));
            DrawAWallStructure(line.GetPosition(3), line.GetPosition(0));
        }
    }

    public void DrawAWallStructure(Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2)
    {
        float Ancho = 3;
        float Alto = 10;
        Transform myWall = Instantiate(myCube, point1, Quaternion.identity,      line.transform.parent).transform;
        posC = ((point2 - point1) * 0.5F) + point1;
        float lengthC = (point2 - point1).magnitude;
        float sineC = (point2.z - point1.z) / lengthC;
        float angleC = Mathf.Asin(-sineC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if (point2.x < point1.x)
        {
            angleC = 0 - angleC;
        }
        myWall.transform.position = posC;
        myWall.localScale = new Vector3(lengthC + 0.1f, Ancho, Alto);
        myWall.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angleC, 0f);
    }
```

I just need a way to adjust the corners to fit perfectly whatever the angle maybe between the walls

Comment: You would need to alter the vertices of your mesh.  First determine the intersection of the lines (on the y planes) at each corner.  You need 2 intersections per corner, inside and outside.  Then position the vertices at their respective intersections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hijinxbassist
The method you just recommended can work when the angle between the two walls is greater, but if I keep reducing the angle between the two walls, let's say for example the walls have an angle of 5 degrees, can you imagine what will be the outer intersection point of those walls? It will be useless to expand the walls that much. Or can you give a better recommendation for such a case?

Comment: You could make a line connecting those vertices, then create the face from the upper and lower lines.

Comment: @hijinxbassist thanks. Both of your suggestions were very useful.